# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/naming/ldap/LdapName

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, android-proguard

I have implemented ProGuard to cut off unnecessary codes. But after the app starts, I am getting the following error -

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/naming/ldap/LdapName;
 at b.a.b.e.d.a.b(Unknown Source)
 at b.a.b.e.d.a.a(Unknown Source)
 at b.a.b.e.d.a.a(Unknown Source)
 at b.a.b.e.d.a.a(Unknown Source)
 at b.a.b.e.d.f.a(Unknown Source)
 at b.a.b.e.d.f.a(Unknown Source)
 at b.a.b.e.d.f.a(Unknown Source)
 at b.a.b.h.c.h.a(Unknown Source)
 at b.a.b.h.c.p.a(Unknown Source)
 at b.a.b.h.b.o.a(Unknown Source)
 at b.a.b.h.b.o.a(Unknown Source)
 at b.a.b.h.b.a.a(Unknown Source)
 at b.a.b.h.b.h.a(Unknown Source)
 at b.a.b.h.b.h.a(Unknown Source)
 at b.a.b.h.b.h.execute(Unknown Source)
 at com.c.a.ae.a(Unknown Source)
 at com.c.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
 at com.c.a.aa.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.naming.ldap.LdapName" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/bd.com.chalo-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/bd.com.chalo-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/bd.com.chalo-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
 ... 19 more
 Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.naming.ldap.LdapName
  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
  ... 20 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

What should I do now? Does it something to do with my library?

Comment: you have to use retrace with your mapping.txt and then check where the error occurs. Then adjust your proguard rules.

Answer (score 0):

Android’s documentation for ProGuard describes it like so:

“The ProGuard tool shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with semantically obscure names. The result is a smaller sized .apk file that is more difficult to reverse engineer…. Having ProGuard run is completely optional, but highly recommended.”

Now adding proguard can cause problems if your app contain third party libraries, broadcast receivers, custom widgets etc.. so you need to add proguard rules to add this classes in runtime otherwise the classes will not compile in APK version and you will get errors

For details about proguard and it's usage see this link:http://omgitsmgp.com/2013/09/09/a-conservative-guide-to-proguard-for-android/

there is a standard proguard rules form which you can use:

```
# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Obfuscation parameters:
#-dontobfuscate
-useuniqueclassmembernames
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-allowaccessmodification

# Ignore warnings:
#-dontwarn org.mockito.**
#-dontwarn org.junit.**
#-dontwarn com.robotium.**
#-dontwarn org.joda.convert.**

# Ignore warnings: We are not using DOM model
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer
# Ignore warnings: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/FAQs
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.**
# Ignore warnings: https://github.com/square/okio/issues/60
-dontwarn okio.**
# Ignore warnings: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/435
-dontwarn com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.**

# Keep the pojos used by GSON or Jackson
-keep class com.futurice.project.models.pojo.* { ; }

# Keep GSON stuff
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.* { ; }

-keep public class Socket

# Keep Jackson stuff
-keep class org.codehaus.* { ; }
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.* { ; }

# Keep these for GSON and Jackson
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Annotation
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod

# Keep Retrofit
-keep class retrofit.* { ; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.** *;
}
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @retrofit.** *;
}
-keep public class com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:2.1.1.* { ; }
# Keep Picasso
-keep class com.squareup.picasso.* { ; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.picasso.** *;
}
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.picasso.** *;
}
```

add this rules in your proguard files ...
For details of the standard form see this:https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices/blob/master/templates/rx-architecture/app/proguard-rules.pro

and this:
https://gist.github.com/Jackgris/c4a71328b1ae346cba04